# How to assign vectors to Linkedlist?

Tags: c++

How do you assign vector to a linkedlist ?
For example is, I have a vector of Cars and a `Linkedlist<Owner> owners.`
Owner is a class itself, so is Linkedlist.

How do I assign these vector of cars to the linkedlist owners ?

Comment: How is Owner defined?

Comment: Are `owners` and `cars` the same size?

Comment: Please provide more code.

Comment: Do you mean that you want each `Owner` to have its own vector of `Car`? In that case you dont assign the vectors to the `LinkedList`. You make the `Car` vector an attribute of `Owner`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Car
{
    //some code...
}

class Owner
{
    private:
        vector<Car> cars;

        //more code here...
};
```

This way each `Owner`-object contains a vector of `Car`.

Comment: I need to use Linkedlist. It is a must.

Comment: In what way? If you add this to your current code(i guess, because we havent seen much) you can use your LinkedList as before. The difference is that each Owner object in your LinkedList now has a vector of Cars.